# Upper bound for area on sphere

Tags: probability, geometry, inequality, spheres

Consider the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \|x\|_2=1\}$, and let $A^\epsilon_x:= \{z \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}:\langle z,x \rangle \ge \epsilon\}$ where $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Note that $A^\epsilon_x$ is slightly less than half of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ (if $\epsilon=0$, it'd be exactly half).

We are only concerned with the area/volume of $A^\epsilon_x$, so the $x$ is arbitrary and I will drop the subscript.

In my reading I came across this claim:

> For all $\epsilon \in (0,1/\sqrt{2})$, $$\mathbb{P}(A^\epsilon) \le (1-\epsilon^2)^{n/2}.$$

[The probability distribution is the uniform distribution.]

How do you prove this claim?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = (1,0,0,0,\ldots)$.  You want the fraction of sphere with $x_1 \geq \epsilon$. This means all other coordinates are at most $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}$, by Pythagoras' theorem.  The volume is at most the volume of a surrounding rectangular box with dimensions $(1-\epsilon)$ in the $x_1$ direction and $(1-\epsilon^2)^{1/2}$ in the other $n-1$ directions.  This box volume upper bound is

$ V \leq (1-\epsilon){(1-\epsilon^2)}^\frac{n-1}{2} \leq (1-\epsilon^2)^{n/2}$

This is almost what you requested except it is the fraction of volume, not the surface area.

Comment: I understand everything you've written and now the bound $(1-\epsilon^2)^{n/2}$ makes a lot of sense. However, I am fairly certain the context is talking about the $(n-1)$-dimensional surface area and not the $n$-dimensional volume. I'll think about it some more. Thank you!

Comment: Note also that if this were talking about the volume, then you would have to divide everything by $\frac{4}{3} \pi$.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the bound be $(1-\epsilon) (2\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2})^{n-1}$? The other coordinates lie in $[\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2},\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}]$.

Comment: Note that you can add to $V$ the part connecting the figure A to the center of the sphere (a sort of cone) and this does not add a lot of volume for large $n$ as long as $\epsilon$ is positive.  But that slightly adjusted volume is $nS$ with $S$ the surface area you are trying to bound.  So within a factor of $n$ asymptotically we can get the same bound on surface area.

Comment: Ah, yes, there will be factors of $2$.  Though if you consider the geometry more carefully and approximate the area by a pyramidal polyhedron with vertex $x$ there may be a factor like $1/n!$ in the volume formula that suppresses it, so I am not sure it is a problem or not.